# Compiler Warning: Execution reaches the end of a value-returning function without returning a value

Tags: c++, c++17

The task given to me was:

John has some amount of money of which he wants to deposit (`f0`) to the bank at the beginning of year 1. He wants to withdraw each year for his living an amount `c0`.

Here is his banker plan:

First, deposit `f0` units of money at the beginning of year 1.

Since his bank account has an interest rate of `p%` per year,
John can withdraw `c0` units of money whenever he wants each year. However, he must take account of an inflation of `i%` per year in order to keep his quality of living. The value `i` is supposed to stay constant over the years.

My solution to calculate and update John's bank account:

```
class BankerPlan{
public:
    static bool fortune(int f0, double p, int c0, int n, double i){
        if(f0 > 0){
            if(n == 0){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                fortune(f0 + (f0 * p / 100) - c0 , p , c0 + (c0 * i / 100) , n - 1, i);
            }
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
   }
};
```

I receive this warning from my compiler:

```
 warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

1 warning generated.

 runtime error: execution reached the end of a value-returning function without returning a value
```

Can somebody please tell me why this happens, and how to prevent it from happening in the future?

Comment: Perhaps you meant `return fortune(f0 + (f0 * p / 100) - c0 , p , c0 + (c0 * i / 100) , n - 1, i);`?

Comment: Hint: If one branch of your `if` has a mandatory `return` you don't need an `else`.

Comment: @tadman In this case, I think removing the second `else` will get rid of the warning but logic will still be wrong.

Comment: @cigien Removing the `else` has absolutely no effect. That code will only run if the `if` has not already tripped the `return` anyway. It's basically wrapped and indented for no reason. The first `if` should also be re-written as a guard clause, like `if (f0 <= 0) { return false; }` which means the rest can be de-indented as well, simplifying the structure.

Comment: ⟼This code could benefit greatly by adopting an [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) and applying it consistently. Indentation conveys structure and intent which makes it easier for us to understand your code without having to invest a lot of time deciphering it, and it can also make mistakes more obvious as they stand out visually.

Comment: "warning: control may reach end of non-void function" - Yeah. The compiler is absolutely correct. What's unclear about the message? Your function doesn't return a value on all control flow paths. That's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving the compiler warning because the program has managed to exit your function without returning a value, even though your function has a return type of `bool`.

On `line 11` of your code, you type `fortune(f0 + (f0 * p / 100) - c0 , p , c0 + (c0 * i / 100) , n - 1, i)`, which doesn't actually do anything because you call it without addressing the value returned at all. To fix this, add a `return` at the beginning of the line:

```
static bool fortune(int f0, double p, int c0, int n, double i){
    if(f0 > 0){
        if(n == 0){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return fortune(f0 + (f0 * p / 100) - c0 , p , c0 + (c0 * i / 100) , n - 1, i);
        }
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also note that when you have an `if-else` where one branch has a `return`, you can omit the `else`.